# (x)Ubuntu : How Can I revert 2 keyboard keys on my laptop ? Or having same function for 2 different keys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, lenovo, keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm using a Lenovo P14s laptop and I want to the "FN" key (with is as bottom left corner) acts same as "Ctrl" key.

How can I do this ?

So far I've tried to map FN on Ctrl key like this :

I add the following line on my local `.Xmodmap` file :

```
keycode 151 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
```

Plus I've also comment the line `key <I151>   {      [ XF86WakeUp            ]       };` in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet` file.

Then `xev` gives me :

For CTRL key :

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x7800001,
    root 0x97c, subw 0x0, time 5466327, (167,-13), root:(1038,462),
    state 0x4, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

for FN key :

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x7800001,
    root 0x97c, subw 0x0, time 5498099, (164,-11), root:(1035,464),
    state 0x0, keycode 151 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

As it didn't work I've also add this line `key <I151> { [ Control_L     ]   };`  in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` file and it didn't work neither

even when I comment `key <LCTL> {   [ Control_L     ]   };`

(for each step I've deleted `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*` and reboot)

For example I can assure you I type `FN + C` I don't copy a text as `CTRL+C` does... What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Perhaps BIOS settings, please have a look at [this](https://support.lenovo.com/pe/en/solutions/ht074187).

Comment: OMG thanks a lot ! That fixed my problem ! How can I mark your comment as solution ?

Comment: You're welcome. It is not my idea and you are perhaps 1000th person asked this question and not really related to Ubuntu. Honor to be at your service.